# How to make one scroll animation in jQuery without external plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a i page web page. It is working fine but no scrolling animation.
how do i make it scroll smoothly. Now it just jumping..
check this url : http://www.theteamconsultancy.com/team/product_marketing.html

```
    div class="services-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="#service-0" data-offset="-200">business consulting</a></li>
    <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="#service-1">product marketing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#service-2">real estate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#service-3">event management</a></li>
    <li><a href="#service-4">healthcare</a></li>
    <li><a href="#service-5">leagal consulting</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.services-nav {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 250px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.services-nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.services-nav ul li {
    background-color: #002E5B;
    border: 1px solid #002E5B;
    border-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.services-nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 8px 20px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.services-nav ul li:before {
    right: 101%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    border-color: #61ADDF;
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-right-color: #61ADDF;
    border-width: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}
.services-nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #61ADDF;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid #61ADDF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #61ADDF;
}
.services-nav ul li:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
    border-width: 15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

Comment: Curious that you are happy to use jQuery but do not want to use another library to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: scroll smoothly ? you want to make the scroll scroll only on fixed steps and this movement to be animated is that it?

Comment: Ah I see you want to animate the scroll when clicking on the menu on the right side. Clarify your question pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to cache $('html, 'body') before scrolling and use event delegation.

```
var $htmlBody = $('html, body');

$htmlBody.on('click', '.services-nav li a', function() {
   var target = $(this).attr('href')
   var offsetTop = $(target).offset().top || 0;
   $htmlBody.animate({scrollTop: offsetTop}, 1500);
   return false;
});
```

Comment: is it possible to change background-color for services-nav ul li when section is loaded? please check  http://www.theteamconsultancy.com/team/product_marketing.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
jQuery('.services-nav ul li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var obj = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(obj).offset().top
    }, 1000); // can change time duration 
});
```

Comment: ` obj = jQuery("#"+jQuery(this).attr('href'));` ?